# What is the expected length of the longest path in a DAG?

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs, directed-graphs

Let's consider a random directed acyclic graph (DAG) with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. What is the expected length of the longest path in this graph? Is there a function $f(n,m)$ that can approximate this value? Or some kind of $O(f(n, m))$ expression?

I have run some calculations and e.g. for $n = 300, m = 400$ average length of the longest path was something around 8.2. For $n = 500, m = 1200$ it was around 13.

Comment: I would be grateful at least for a link to some scientific paper that I missed.

Comment: How would you define/construct your random DAG model? You could couple it with the standard $G(n,m)$ model if your model has some nice "monotonic" properties.

Comment: Maybe it's not the best way to generate a random DAG, but I was thinking about randomly choosing $m$ edges from all edges (i.e. pairs $(a,b)$ where $1 \leq a < b \leq n$).

Comment: @Jakubussimus In this way, some graphs (up to isomorphism) are more likely, but it's not a problem for me. But, if it's easier to solve this problem, you can take any random DAG definition you like (including but not limited to choosing one graph from all nonisomorphic DAGs with $n$ vertices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked in a talk by Peter J. Cameron.  Here are the [slides](https://cameroncounts.github.io/web/talks/14eindhoven/ao.pdf) from the talk (see question 2 at the end).  The problem is still open to my knowledge, but a very precise answer (asymptotic mean, variance, and central limit theorem) were provided for the special case of acyclic orientations of complete bipartite graphs in my Ph.D student Jessica Khera's thesis [thesis](https://fau.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fau%3A78732/datastream/OBJ/view/LONESUM_MATRICES_AND_ACYCLIC_ORIENTATIONS__ENUMERATION_AND_ASYMPTOTICS.pdf).  See Theorem 2.5.2.

Comment: Sadly, the second link is not working.

Comment: hmm... both links are working for me, but maybe I have institutional access to the thesis allowing the link to work.  Here is the Math Review number MR4272248 if it helps to find a way to access it through mathscinet.

Comment: Found in the [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20221001000000*/http://purl.flvc.org/fau/fd/FA00013716). Thanks!